# Display ProgressDialog from non-activity Volley class

Tags: java, android, android-volley, progressdialog

I am trying to display a ProgressDialog while my app is getting data from a web service. I also would like to call a method in MapsActivity (main activity) when DataController is done adding objects from parsing web service.

In my code nothing happens (i.e. no ProgressDialog appears) and I'm stuck on how to let MapsActivity know that the objects have been created.

As you can see I've tried to make the ProgressDialog appear with

```
pd.show(context, "text", "text")
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private DataController controller = new DataController(MapsActivity.this);

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        sharedPref = new SharedPreference(MapsActivity.this);
        storedLikes = controller.readLike(sharedPref);
        //This runs getLikedPos() in DataController

        /Lots of code....
```

**DataController.Java**

```
public class DataController {
// Fields

public DataController(MapsActivity mapsActivity) {
    this.context = mapsActivity;
}

public void getLikedPos() {

    this.url = getUrl();

    JsonObjectRequest jrequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "In progress", "Loading");
                        int success = response.getInt("success");

                        if (success == 1) {
                            JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("spots");

                            for (int i=0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject spot = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                                Location location = new Location("");
                                location.setLatitude(spot.getDouble(LIKE_LAT));
                                location.setLongitude(spot.getDouble(LIKE_LONG));

                                int id = spot.getInt(LIKE_ID);

                                String time = spot.getString(LIKE_TIMESTAMP);
                                Calendar parsedTime = convertDate(time);
                                likeArr.add(new Like(location, id, parsedTime));
                            }
                            System.out.println("Size of LikeArr ArrayList after parsing: " + likeArr.size());
                            pd.dismiss();
                            //context.updateMap();   ??
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();    
                    }

                }
            }
            , new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please look at `AsyncTask`. This provides a mechanism to do exactly what you want and you should find tons of tutorials with examples about how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've read many times that there is no need to use AsyncTask when using Volley. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Just one thing - `onResponse()` is called after the response is actually delivered. If you want to show a meaningful progress dialog, I suggest you do it before you add the request to the queue. The dismiss logic is fine as it is.

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about Volley. I missed that in the question description. Just ignore me.